# Looker studio failed to fetch data from underlying dataset even though query works fine in BigQuery, suspecting it's because JavaScript function

Tags: sql, json, regex, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a database with two columns, one is a date and the other is a string formatted as JSON as follows:

```
'{ "k1": 1, "k2": 2, "k3": 3 }'
```

I am trying to get a table to use in Looker Studio, where for each date I have as many rows as there are keys in the corresponding JSON. For example if the above example corresponds to today's date, I want to have the rows:
`today, k1, 1`, `today, k2, 2`, `today, k3, 3` in my table.

The challenge is **I don't know the names of the keys `k1`, `k2`, `k3`** in advance, and there could be more or less of them depending on the date.

I have seen people solve this on the internet using JavaScript (because apparently even though BigQuery SQL can process JSON, it's actually quite lacking in versatility when doing it - to use an euphemism for "utterly incompetent in terms of functionality").

So I have this mockup code:

```sql
-- works in bigquery but not in looker studio (failed to fetch data from underlying dataset)
CREATE TEMP  FUNCTION EXTRACT_KV_PAIRS(json_str STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY< STRUCT<key string, value string> >
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try{ 
    const json_dict = JSON.parse(json_str); 
    const all_kv = Object.entries(json_dict).map(
        (r)=>Object.fromEntries([["key", r[0]],["value",  
                                   JSON.stringify(r[1])]]));
    return all_kv;
  } catch(e) { return [{"key": "error","value": e}];}
""";
with
data
as
(
  select 
    cast('2024-01-10' as date) as date, '{"a": 12, "b": 11, "c": 51}' as json_string
  union all
  select 
    cast('2024-01-11' as date), '{"a": 3, "b": 2 , "d": 124}'
) -- data should act as a database table
,
extracted_pairs as
(SELECT data.date as date,
    EXTRACT_KV_PAIRS(data.json_string) as kv_list 
FROM data
)
SELECT
extracted_pairs.date as `date`, item.key as `key`, item.value as `value`
FROM extracted_pairs
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(extracted_pairs.kv_list) as item
```

So finding key-value pairs is done in javascript in the function EXTRACT_CV_PAIRS, which returns an array of structs, which we then cross join with.

**This works wonderfully in BigQuery itself, but it fails in Looker Studio! Looker studio tells me "Failed to fetch data from the underlying dataset." even though, again, the BigQuery query returns preciesely the expected results.**

I was thinking that it's because of the JavaScript, so I tried another solution I found here, using regular expressions:

```sql
with
data
as
(
  select 
    cast('2024-01-10' as date) as date, '{"a": 12, "b": 11, "c": 51}' as json_string
  union all
  select 
    cast('2024-01-11' as date), '{"a": 3, "b": 2 , "d": 124}'
) -- data should act as a database table
SELECT
      data.`date`, key, value
FROM sku_db
    , UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(data.json_string), r'"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*([^,}]+)')) AS item
CROSS JOIN UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(item, ':')[OFFSET(0)] AS key, SPLIT(item, ':') [OFFSET(1)] AS value)])
```

However, this doesn't work in BigQuery even because the regular expression used to extract strings of the form `"a":12` contains two capture groups! (the reason being that BigQuery uses re2, which does not support multiple capture groups - of course, who would have expected versatility from this querying engine at this point). I also tried capturing the key and the values directly, but again re2 does not allow the regex that would be required for that, because for example to capture the keys one would need the regexp `"([^"]+)"\s*(?=:)` and the "`(?=:)`" part is, what a surprise, unsupported...

One more option that I haven't tried is creating a view, as I heard that looker studio sometimes doesn't take well to data coming from bigquery queries without giving any reasonable explanation given... I could go that route, but I avoided it because I currently don't have permission to create views in the project.

So before going that way - which is of course not guaranteed to work - I decided to ask: Besides what I've tried, is there any other way of achieving something as (seemingly) simple as extracting the key-value pairs from a column of simple JSONs with unknown keys in BigQuery, a way which would also happen to work in Looker Studio? Many thanks to whomever would think of another way to achieve this.

Comment: Looker Studio might not work with multi-statement BQ scripts (temp function + select query). Have you tried making EXTRACT_KV_PAIRS a persistent function in BQ so Looker doesn't need the temp definition?

Comment: @joe That would be an idea, better than making a view even, but I am lacking permissions to create views or basically to store anything within BigQuery itself, so I can't store this function either. How would I just store a function though? I know how I would store a table or a view if I had permissions, but not a function.

Comment: Very similar to a view. CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `<project>.<dataset>.EXTRACT_KV_PAIRS`(json_str STRING)
RETURNS.... Then in your query you'd qualify the function name with the project/dataset without having to declare the temp function.